# Django FilePathField

Tags: django, django-models

```
field_name = models.FilePathField(path=None, match=None, recursive=False, max_length=100, **options)
```

Hi guys, has anyone used the FilePathField?
What filesystem is it referring to, the client filesystem or the server filesystem that is stores a Char path to?

Comment: Come on guys anyone, is it the filesystem of which the Django app is running or the filesystem of the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FilePathField** instances are created in your database as varchar columns with a default max length of 100 characters. As with other fields, you can change the maximum length using the max_length argument.

You work with server file system if we talk about models... So it'll save file path to your local storage. If U want to use Client files, you should use **FileField** with *upload_to* param. Than Django ORM save is in DB as VarChar field too and upload file. Before that, you have to add **MEDIA_ROOT** in settings_file